# Invalid time value in Date Picker React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

When I choose a date from date picker I want to display it in the `Item` component `console.log(this.props.endDate)` gets error 'Range invalid time'. I use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      endDate: new Date()
    };
  }

  handle = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      endDate: date
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Item
          endDate = {this.state.endDate}
          handle = {this.handle}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.endDate)
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.props.endDate}
          onChange={this.props.handle()}
          showTimeSelect
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          timeIntervals={15}
          dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
          timeCaption="time"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which DatePicker library do you use ?

Comment: @MaximeGirou https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Comment: try `this.props.handle` instead of `this.props.handle()`

Comment: Your code is working fine, except the error of `maximum state update` due to `onChange={this.props.handle()}`, which should be `onChange={this.props.handle}`

Comment: @MihaiT  it doesn't work

Comment: @ravibagul91 In google chrome my application works,  to mozilla doesn't  work

Comment: It's working fine in mozilla too. Can you create a codepen?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I can't reproduce this error. :(

Comment: so there's an error but you cannot reproduce it ? that's strange :)

Comment: In that case voting to close this as non-reproduciable.

Comment: @MihaiT I don't know why this happens. I can't explain why Mozilla doesn't work and Chrome works.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I don't know why this happens. I can't explain why Mozilla doesn't work and Chrome works.

Comment: I created a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-vaughan-4xc2e) with your code and the fix suggested by @Mihai T. It works both in chrome and firefox without any errors.

Comment: Well if this error cannot be reproduced it might be  a problem with some other part of code you are using.

Comment: @MihaiT When I delete `this.props.endDate` inside selected={this.props.endDate} doesn't have error

Comment: `Range invalid time` is the exact error you get ? try changing: `onChange={date => this.props.handle(date)}` if it doesn't work, console.log(date) inside `handle` function and tell me what you get.

Comment: @MihaiT I have another errors. Apart from 'invalid time'. I have: Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    React 13
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:255
    React 7

    Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: Did you try the above solution ? If it did not work please tell me what `console.log(date)` returns from `handle` function.After you change the default detate.

Comment: @MihaiT I choose the date normally. I have the date of the object. The problem is when this date is passed back to the datepicker for editing

Comment: That's why i am asking you to tell me what date you have in the `handle` function. Maybe the format is wrong.

Comment: @MihaiT date_end: "2019-06-30 21:59:59.999+00"